# What is the technical text below reviews in the Windows Phone Dev Center?

Tags: apps, store

In the Windows Phone Dev Center, you can view the reviews of your apps. This includes the name of the reviewer and the date when it was reviewed. Under that, there is, sometimes, some sort of technical tag. Does anyone know what it means and when it is added/omitted?

Below you can see an example. For Sven, there is no technical tag, for Gert, there is 'RM-846_eu_belgium_264'.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RM-846 [Specifies](http://www.nokia.com/global/declaration/declaration-of-conformity) a Lumia 620. The link shows a bunch of models and Nokia's internal model designation.

Also a [bing search](http://www.bing.com/search?q=nokia%20phone%20rm-846&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=nokia%20phone%20rm-846&sc=0-0&sp=-1&sk=) or [google search](https://www.google.com/#safe=active&hl=en&biw=1366&bih=768&sclient=psy-ab&q=nokia+phone+rm-846&oq=nokia+phone+rm-846&gs_l=hp.3...1791.1791.0.3864.1.1.0.0.0.0.184.184.0j1.1.0...0.0...1c.1.12.psy-ab.cVQeJaBJtZ8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46471029,d.aWM&fp=a5311ae5763fe44d) provides similar confirmation.

I would assume that eu_belgium depicts either the specific country the phone was made for, or the current language settings.